# How could I simulate projectile collision agaisnt RTS units with primitive colliders?

Tags: collision-detection, rts, projectile-physics, collider

For example, humans are easy they are just capsules. But for cavalry, an arrow could hit the horse or the rider. Right now cavalry are also capsule colliders for unit-unit collision, but for projectiles I would need to detect hits on the rider too.

Would a compound collides be the solution? In the Total War series, it looks like arrows have full mesh collision with units. [Here is a video](https://youtu.be/G_4coOy3Pjo?t=148) showing arrows hitting different parts of the models accurately-- It shows how arrows can hit limbs and the head idk how that is done in such a scale.)

How is this done?

Comment: I'd be surprised if an RTS used collision detection for adjudicating hits at that scale at all. I'd expect more often they'd determine in advance by PRNG whether a shot will hit or miss (or hit the horse or rider, if applicable), then animate the projectile to visualize that pre-determined outcome.

Comment: So they would pick a collision sport on the mesh? What if the unit changes direction mid arrow flight?

Comment: That sounds like a question you can edit your post to ask instead, if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Like DMGregory said: it's very unlikely Total War is actually *simulating* physics for all those arrows. There's probably a big separation from the battle simulation and the actual animations in game.

Here's a [GDC talk](https://youtu.be/6OkhjWUIUf0) about "predictable projectiles" which could be used for the animation side of things.